# Move DataTable colmn based on column group and column move within group

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently below code I used for [Datatable.net](https://datatables.net) library for column moving. I need column moving within column group. How can I achieve this?

```
var table = $('#evidenceTable').DataTable({
    colReorder: { fixedColumnsLeft: 1, realtime: false },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis', text: 'Show/Hide Columns', className:'btn btn-alt'
        }
    ]
});

table.on('column-reorder', function (e, settings, details) {
    console.log('details : ');
    console.log(details);
}
});
```

Check the JSFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjay_kewat/6rat0n1c/) for my problem.